# Redirection fail on Apache2 for SSL subdomain configuration

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl, ssl-certificate, subdomain

On my Apache2 server I've enabled this 3 subdomain sites.

**database.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName database.example.com
  ServerAlias www.database.example.com
  DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/
  Redirect permanent / https://database.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName  database.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/phpmyadmin/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/database.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/database.example.com-access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com_INTERMEDIATE.cer

</VirtualHost>
```

**staging.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName staging.example.com
ServerAlias www.staging.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/staging

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  Redirect permanent / https://staging.example.com

</VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName staging.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/staging

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/staging.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/staging.example.com-access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com_INTERMEDIATE.cer

 </VirtualHost>
```

**preprod.example.com**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName preprod.example.com
ServerAlias www.preprod.example.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/preprod

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 Redirect permanent / https://preprod.example.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName preprod.example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/preprod

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/preprod.example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/preprod.example.com-access.log combined

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/example.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/example.com_INTERMEDIATE.cer

 </VirtualHost>
```

Connection to database and staging works fine but when try to connect to `preprod.example.com` the server redirects me to `database.example.com` with an `ssl_error_bad_cert_domain` error. The certificate that I'm using has been provided to me from my domain provider and is valid for `*.example.com`.

Can somebody help me to understand what is the issue here and help me to solve it? Thank's a lot for that!

Comment: Are you connecting to `preprod.example.com` or to `www.preprod.example.com`? It makes a big difference.

Comment: I'm conecting to preprod.example.com

Comment: This wouldn't be caused by your browser's cache?

Comment: No, I can reproduce this behaviour on different browsers and after cleaning cache.

Comment: The configuration has been reloaded or Apache restarted since you've added these domains?  The configs you show are included into the main configuration?  There's no other software in front of Apache?

Comment: Perhaps you could add logs for database.example.com too?

Comment: You should find the following message in the error log when Apache is started: "Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS server name indication support (RFC 4366)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, that here was nothing wrong with my Apache2 config. In the WordPress config was an wrong URL saved, so WordPress has redirected my requests.

Comment: Good to hear you solved this, but a pro-tip right here for debugging stuff like this: Open up the Terminal and run this Curl command: `curl -ILk preprod.example.com`. That command will show you the headers connected to the HTTP request and you can follow the chain to see what is redirecting to what. In this case it seems like there were 2-3 hops. By seeing the headers you will better be able to focus on what might be causing the underlying behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip 